# Why is my Swift app archive so large?

Tags: ios, swift, archive

I wrote my first iOS app in 2012 in Objective-C. Its total archive size including the app file, dSYMs file, etc. was less than 1 MB. I recently rewrote it in Swift with Xcode 9 and its archive size is now 160 MB. What is taking up all the space? It's not my code, because the Swift code is very similar to the Objective-C code and is actually a fair amount smaller.

I'm using Google Maps in another app and noticed the archive size is almost a half GB. I thought maybe the Google Maps libraries were taking up all the space until I noticed that all my recent Swift apps are very large as well. My related question is: If I'm enabling Bitcode (as is required), and my .app file size is 200 MB, how much of that is actually downloaded on the user's iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

Every Swift app has the Swift runtime statically linked. The reason for this is that they still have not achieved a stable ABI so Swift apps compiled with different versions of the compiler cannot share the same runtime.

Comment: Yikes. If that's true, that's ridiculous. Why can't the app just contain the runtime it needs to run and not carry with it code it doesn't use?

Comment: @KenM Probably because it does need that code would be my guess.

Comment: This is still the case.

Comment: I can't believe this is still the case. I remember thinking *years* ago I hope they deal with this soon. Man, remember when you could compile a C++ app to an executable a couple hundred kilobytes large? Whatever happened Apple…

Comment: @devios1 Swift 5 stabilises the ABI which will improve things immensely and it's due for release fairly shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Apple did this only in iOS 12.2+ and Swift 5. [Here's Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/swift-5-release-notes-for-xcode-10_2). Since iOS 12.2 archives don't include swift libs.